# Explicit use of EntityManager with Spring Data repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

When do I need to explicitly resort to EntityManager methods(I'm particularly interested in clear(), close(), flush(), detach()) inside my Service methods that additionally work with Spring Data repos?

I'm mostly interested in a general insight into the subject.
Let's say in one application I found this:

```
    for ( MyEntity myEntity: entities) {
        ...some logic here
        mySpringDataRepo.save ( myEntity );
    }
    entityManager.flush ();
    entityManager.clear ();
```

I found such use of EntityManager justifiable since the memory can be overloaded with the entities.
However, in another code snippet:

```
    mySpringDataRepository.save(entity);
    entityManager.detach(entity);
```

Is it necessary to explicitly detach the entity? Doesn't Spring Data handle it by itself?

I also found this post:
http://newscentral.exsees.com/item/de38b01b7a9f794a124e2c72b97d1103-c5533957a4140e3c51e7d295ec840d08

which confused me even more.

As for the close() method I believe there's no need to call it in the EE environment. Am I correct?

PS: my configurations are very mainstream: JpaTransactionManager/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about entity managers. If you want to manually flush call the flush method on the repository, or saveAndFlush if saving entities one by one. Personally I don't bother, my repository method calls are from a transactional service, and when that method executes the commit ends up doing a flush.

By the way you don't need to loop through a collection to save each entity. Just do a save on the collection.

Comment: Just a small amendment: The repositories have to extend JpaRepository to access the methods flush and saveAndFlush. CrudRepository does not contain those methods.

Comment: @Paul, I'm aware of the option to save the whole collection at once, but in this particular case it was done that way for a reason. See, where I put  "...some logic here" is actually quite a few lines of code that should be processed in the traversal.

Comment: @PaulNUK: What if we use several different repos in a scope of one transaction/one user request/one transactional method? Will all of them use the same instance of EntityManager or a new one for every repo?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you wired them up in the first place, but assuming you wired them with the same EntityManagerFactory they should use the same entity manager, as the usual way of doing things is to have one entity manager for each database schema you're connecting to.

Answer (score 5):

I'd argue that repository clients should *never, ever* interact with a lower layer API than the repository itself. Interacting with data access APIs is what a repository is supposed to abstract.

If you think about it, it raises a lot of problems:

- mocking the repository to test the service is not enough anymore, you'd have to also mock the `EntityManager`.
- why should a service know about the `EntityManager` in the first place?
- what, if you decided to switch to a JDBC based implementation of the repository? You'd have to touch the service's code, too.

So the answer is pretty simple: determine what your actual use case is. If standard Spring Data mechanisms (query methods, executing predicates) don't allow to model that out of the box, add a custom implementation as e.g. described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) and implement that functionality *inside* the repository. And no, `em.detach()` is *not* a use-case.